# How to always have a blank placeholder row for new records in AG Grid?

Tags: ag-grid

How do I set up AG Grid such that there is always a blank placeholder row at the bottom for new records? So that it behaves like Excel, or like Slickgrid when enableAddRow is true.

Answer (score 0):

When passing the `rowData` array to the grid component, you can include an extra object with blank values.

For example, if you had a grid of `Employee` objects with attributes `name` and `title`, the following would work with ES6:
`rowData=[ ...existingEmployees, { name: '', title: '' } ]`